# Secure way to send http post message bug report

Tags: c++, http, rsa, bug-reporting

I'm developing bug reporting, for when a C++ program crashes.

**Task:**

Program crashes; it sends some info to a server, while user sees "Something bad happened, sorry".

**Solution:**

I've written a script on the server, which gets the HTTP POST message. My program sends POST messages with helpful info. It is not secure. With some http sniffer, one can find out where the POST messages go, and send lots of fake bug reports. I've decided to use RSA for this. I've used the **crypto++** library to do this.

**Question:**

I have bad feeling, that I am making it really much harder than it has to be. Is there any way to implement **this way** of bug reporting more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach this by 1) using an encrypted connection (HTTPS) to your server, and 2) using a private shared key in your application that encodes a time-based token that your server verifies is the correct key and ~roughly the correct time.

Comment: However attackers could still dig the private key embedded in the application to forge the time token, could they not?

Comment: Absolutely.  Would take a much more advanced attacker and concerted effort though...

Comment: +1, it is always about the strength of the attacker.